# How to move google map zoom control position in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I managed to get google map up and running. The problem is current design of the app that I'm developing overlap the zoom control in google map. How do I move this zoom control to another position?

[image]

Comment: if you want to move the existing default zoom controller to another place, i can help you.

Answer (score 9):

I have found 2 ways to move the GoogleMap zoom controls.  The first is mentioned in @Numan1617's answer, using the `setPadding()` function:

```
googleMap.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Which is very useful for ensuring that the zoom controls are visible when you have a Google **AdView** banner at the bottom of your screen.  Like this:

```
googleMap.setPadding(0,0,0,adViewLayout.getHeight());
```

This will move the lower left Google name, the zoom controls AND the toolbar (which slides in right-to-left when you touch a marker on the map), to just above the layout containing your AdView.  Otherwise these UI controls may be fully or partially behind the **AdView**.

But what if you want finer control than that?  Like move the zoom controls all the way to the corner?  So I dug in and figured out this way to do it:  get the view object that encloses the zoom controls and set new LayoutParams for it.

I also wanted to move the compass and the toolbar so I included code here for those too.

**NOTE**:  the GoogleMap UI Controls have text tags set that make it convenient to access them.  I included all the UI control text tags that I could find.

There does not appear to be a convenient tag on the zoom controls enclosing layout, so I had to get one of the zoom in/zoom out controls and then get it's parent View (ViewGroup actually).  I found that it contains RelativeLayout.LayoutParams, which means that it's enclosing layout is a RelativeLayout.

Here it is in `DisplayMapFragment.java`:

```
package <blah>;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class DisplayMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private static final String TAG = DisplayMapFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String GOOGLEMAP_COMPASS = "GoogleMapCompass";                   // [4]
    private static final String GOOGLEMAP_TOOLBAR = "GoogleMapToolbar";                   // [3]
    private static final String GOOGLEMAP_ZOOMIN_BUTTON = "GoogleMapZoomInButton";        // [2]child[0]
    private static final String GOOGLEMAP_ZOOMOUT_BUTTON = "GoogleMapZoomOutButton";      // [2]child[1]
    private static final String GOOGLEMAP_MYLOCATION_BUTTON = "GoogleMapMyLocationButton";// [0]

    private View mapView = null;

    public DisplayMapFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView()");

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.setRetainInstance(true);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);  // map calls my onMapReady()

        mapView = mapFragment.getView();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady()");

        // move the compass to top center
        moveCompass(mapView,-1,4,-1,-1,true,false);

        // move toolbar to right center
        moveToolbar(mapView,-1,-1,4,-1,false,true);

        // move zoom controls to bottom right
        moveZoomControls(mapView, -1,-1,4,4,false,false);
    }

    /**
     * Move the View according to the passed params.  A -1 means to skip that one.
     *
     * NOTE:  this expects the view to be inside a RelativeLayout.
     *
     * @param view - a valid view
     * @param left - the distance from the left side
     * @param top - the distance from the top
     * @param right - the distance from the right side
     * @param bottom - the distance from the bottom
     * @param horizontal - boolean, center horizontally if true
     * @param vertical - boolean, center vertically if true
     */
    private void moveView(View view, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, boolean horizontal, boolean vertical) {
        try {
            assert view != null;

            // replace existing layout params
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            if (left >= 0) {
                rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            }

            if (top >= 0) {
                rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            }

            if (right >= 0) {
                rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
                rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            }

            if (bottom >= 0) {
                rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            }

            if (horizontal) {
                rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            }

            if (vertical) {
                rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            }

            rlp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);

            view.setLayoutParams(rlp);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "moveView() - failed: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void moveCompass(View mapView, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, boolean horizontal, boolean vertical) {

        assert mapView != null;

        View compass = mapView.findViewWithTag(GOOGLEMAP_COMPASS);

        if (compass != null) {
            moveView(compass,left,top,right,bottom,horizontal,vertical);
        }
    }

    private void moveToolbar(View mapView, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, boolean horizontal, boolean vertical) {

        assert mapView != null;

        View toolbar = mapView.findViewWithTag(GOOGLEMAP_TOOLBAR);

        if (toolbar != null) {
            moveView(toolbar,left,top,right,bottom,horizontal,vertical);
        }
    }

    private void moveZoomControls(View mapView, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, boolean horizontal, boolean vertical) {

        assert mapView != null;

        View zoomIn = mapView.findViewWithTag(GOOGLEMAP_ZOOMIN_BUTTON);

        // we need the parent view of the zoomin/zoomout buttons - it didn't have a tag
        // so we must get the parent reference of one of the zoom buttons
        View zoomInOut = (View) zoomIn.getParent();

        if (zoomInOut != null) {
            moveView(zoomInOut,left,top,right,bottom,horizontal,vertical);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add padding to the controls displayed on the map using `GoogleMap.setPadding()`.

More documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setPadding(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)).